# How many ways we can render in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

During interviews, recruiters asks *"How many types of render are
there in reactjs?"*. What would the proper answer to this question Maybe they want to know how many types we can render in react?

Comment: Have you appeared for the interview or yet to appear? "they may ask" sounds like an assumption.

Comment: Are you sure you have worded the question properly? Sounds like you are implying something else. Explain?

Comment: The proper answer is "What the heck do you mean"?

Comment: do you mean _lifecycle methods_?

Comment: "How many types of render are there in reactjs?" is an incorrect question. The correct question would be "In which conditions, the render method of a React component is triggered"

Comment: @ShubhamoyChakrabarty already attended they are asking the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [React components Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

where there are two main titles "Mounting" and "Updating", obviously on first load the life cycle methods mentioned under "Mounting" are called and on every update the life cycle methods mentioned under "Updating" are called

Comment: This should be a comment imo because you are only linking to the docs. The other sentence is just stating the obvious that "mounting" = mounting and "updating" = updating... Not to mention that you are just assuming what OP means. ☹